cron log shows the job is running but actually the job is failing
I have a cron job in aws ec2 instance defined as:
0 2 * * * /home/ec2-user/scripts/backup.sh
0 3 * * 0 /home/ec2-user/scripts/cleanup.sh
0 * * * * /home/ec2-user/scripts/health_check.sh

I checked whether the jobs are running by :
$ tail -f /var/log/cron
Jun  3 02:00:01 ip-172-31-0-123 CROND[1234]: (ec2-user) CMD (/home/ec2-user/scripts/backup.sh)
Jun  3 03:00:01 ip-172-31-0-123 CROND[1235]: (ec2-user) CMD (/home/ec2-user/scripts/cleanup.sh)
Jun  3 04:00:01 ip-172-31-0-123 CROND[1236]: (ec2-user) CMD (/home/ec2-user/scripts/health_check.sh)
Jun  3 05:00:01 ip-172-31-0-123 CROND[1237]: (ec2-user) CMD (/home/ec2-user/scripts/health_check.sh)

It looked like the jobs are running.
But on manually running one of the jobs, I found that the job was actually failing and throwing an error:
$ /home/ec2-user/scripts/clean_up.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/scripts/worker_script.py", line 15, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Is there any way to know that the jobs are running successfully or not? and log the errors accordingly?

You could track the progress of the scripts by logging what they are doing to a logfile. Why have you named the scripts .sh btw? It looks like they are python scripts.

@TedLyngmo they set the python interpreter and working directory and trigger django manage.py commands.

I see. Well, catch the exception and log it.

You can get the output code of a program using $?. If its a non-zero number then its an error.

@MaximilianBallard what you referred to as output code is an "exit status".

You might want to capture the error in your script, by checking the exit status variable: "$?"
something like this:
command
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "command failed"
  exit 1
fi

Also, you can log the output of your scripts like this:
0 2 * * * /home/ec2-user/scripts/backup.sh 2>&1 | logger -t cron_backup
0 3 * * 0 /home/ec2-user/scripts/cleanup.sh 2>&1 | logger -t cron_cleanup
0 * * * * /home/ec2-user/scripts/health_check.sh 2>&1 | logger -t cron_HC

"cron_backup/cron_cleanup/cron_HC" can be replaced by any tag you want in syslog. In this way, the output of your scrips (both stdout/stderr) will be logged in the "syslog".
